# Finding properties of a real function

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

Is there a way, using `sympy`, to figure out (some) properties of a function, thought of as a real function?

For example, if

```
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> f = Lambda(x, sqrt((x-2)/(x+2)))
```

then something like

```
>>> f.domain()
(-oo, -2) U [2, oo)
>>> f.image()  # there is "imageset", but it is not expanding on the set of reals
[0, 1) U (1, oo)
>>> f.is_injective()
True
>>> f.is_bounded()
False
>>> f.is_even  # currently returns None
False
```

Some of this is implemented in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Some of these properties are likely not implemented. Others have a different meaning, for example is_even is used to query integer parity.

Answer (score 3):

Some of these are implemented in [`sympy.calculus.util`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/calculus/util.py) and [`sympy.calculus.singularities`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/calculus/singularities.py), although they aren't exported to `from sympy import *` yet, so you'd have to import them manually. The functionality for some of them is still limited, so you may not yet get an answer.